# Inno Setup Не удаляемый пустой файл

Tags: inno-setup

Я делал установщик для своей игры и случайно что то напутал из за чего Inno Setup место ярлыка на игру создал пустой файл который я не могу удалить уже очень долго. Удалял все возможными методами не получается удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]